# How to count number of null value in json psql

Tags: json, psql

I have table  as follows

```
---- | --------------------- 
 id  | json
---- | ---------------------
 1   |  [{"score": 6, "r2": null,"r3": null}]
---- | ---------------------
 2   |  [{"score": null, "r2": 1,"r3": 2}]
```

I want to know which keys has number of missing value in each json string. and number of keys has missing value. I have rows over 10 M.

basically I want following output

```
---- | --------------------- |--- |
 id  |  keys                 | n  |
---- | --------------------- |--- |
 1   |  ["r2","r3"]          | 2  |
---- | --------------------- |--- |
 2   |  ["score"]            | 1  |
```

My code is as follow

```
WITH A AS
(SELECT '1' AS id,
      '[{"score": 6, "r2": null,"r3": null}]' AS json_response
UNION SELECT '2' AS id,
       '[{"score": null, "r2": 1,"r3": 2}]' AS json_response)
```

Following code is to just filter out rows which contain null values. I have no idea to think how to create above table. However, following code doesn't select rows which contain missing values

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE json_typeof(json_response::json ->  'nullValue') = 'null'
```

How to build find keys which has missing data?

Thanks